# How Do I Place jQuery Animated Object Inside A HTML Canvas or Div Tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How Do I Place jQuery Animated Object Inside A HTML Canvas or Div Tag?
I have image, which can be moved Right,Left,Up,Down with the click on the button.
Here is what I have worked on so far:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#moveleft').click(function() {
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "-=80px" //moves left
        });
    });
    $('#moveright').click(function() {
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginLeft' : "+=80px" //moves right
        });
    });
    $('#movedown').click(function() {
        $('#textbox').animate({
        'marginTop' : "+=80px" //moves down
        });
    });
    $('#moveup').click(function() {
         $('#textbox').animate({
         'marginTop' : "-=80px" //moves up
        });
    });
});
 </script>
<div style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;>

<div style="padding:20px;"> 
<button id="moveleft">Move Left</button>    
<button id="moveright">Move right</button> 
<button id="movedown">Move Down</button> 
<button id="moveup">Move Up</button></div>
<div id="textbox" style="position:absolute;padding:10px;width:300px;"> 
<img  src="sample.gif">
</div>

<div>
```

Comment: @OP : You question is unclear, the `img` tag is already in a `div`. Do you need to draw this image on canvas?

Comment: Hello A.J, I know that the image tag is already there. I am trying to find a way to limit that animated image within a certain width and height.

Comment: Got it now, you want to limit movement of image within the div ryt? Now suppose it touches the right border of parent div, and I click on move right should not repond(not move at all), ryt?

Comment: Yes. Thats what I meant. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the `offset` and limit you image in parent div.

Here is a example where image is limited for `left` border, extend similar logic for all borders:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var parent = $("#parent");
  var maxLimits = {
    "left": parent.offset().left,
    "right": parent.offset().left + 300,
    "top": parent.offset().top,
    "bottom": parent.offset().top + 100
  }
  $('#moveleft').click(function() {
    if (maxLimits.left > $('img').offset().left - 80) {
      $('img').animate({
        'marginLeft': "=" + maxLimits.left + "px"
      });
    } else {
      $('img').animate({
        'marginLeft': "-=80px" //moves left
      });
    }
  });
  $('#moveright').click(function() {
    $('img').animate({
      'marginLeft': "+=80px" //moves right
    });
  });
  $('#movedown').click(function() {
    $('img').animate({
      'marginTop': "+=80px" //moves down
    });
  });
  $('#moveup').click(function() {
    $('img').animate({
      'marginTop': "-=80px" //moves up
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;>
<div style=" padding:20px; "> 
<button id="moveleft">Move Left</button>    
<button id="moveright">Move right</button> 
<button id="movedown">Move Down</button> 
<button id="moveup">Move Up</button></div>
<div id="parent" style="position:absolute;padding:10px;width:300px;height:100px "> 
<img  height=50px width=50px src="sample.gif ">
</div>
<div>
```